# Unable to Intercept Browser Back Button Press in Next.js Success Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, browser-history

I am currently working on a Next.js application where I've implemented a success page for users who have completed a payment. I want to prevent users from navigating back to the payment page by intercepting the back button press and redirecting them to the home page.

I have tried the following approaches without success:

- Utilizing the **popstate** event listener.
- Using the **beforeunload** event listener.
- Manipulating the browser history with **history.replaceState** and **history.pushState**.

Despite these efforts, the back button press is not triggering the specified handling function. I've confirmed that the success page is being rendered, and other functionalities on the page work as expected.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const handleBackButton = () => {
      router.push('/');
    };

    history.replaceState(null, null, location.href);

    window.addEventListener('popstate', handleBackButton);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handleBackButton);
    };
  }, [router]);
```

in the above code the handleBackButton never got called and I am redirecting to the payment page which is third party payment gateway.

I have tried router.beforePopState and this is also never got called for my case.

I'm using Next.js version 13.5.0.

**Expected Outcome:**

I expect that when a user presses the back button on the success page, they should be redirected to the home page. However, the **handleBackButton** function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I had used `router.replace()` instead of `router.push()` in the same situation.

Comment: I am also using the replace only.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is interesting.....

Go on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) in a new tab
Open Inspect Element and paste the following code in the console:

```js
const stateObj={foo:"bar"}
window.onbeforeunload=function(){
  let url="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77835092"
  history.replaceState(history.state||stateObj,"",url)
}
```

Then click a random question on the dashboard, then click **back** and it will redirect to this question.... so with at least replaceState, it seems you have to set it before the user goes into another page that they will press **back** on

Comment: Because the domain is same but when there is a third party domain like in my case it's payment one This thing is not working